# how to initialize llvm coverage directly from a shared library?

Tags: python, shared-libraries, llvm, gcov, lcov

I am testing a C/C++ shared library where I have compiled the library with the `-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -pg` flags and linked with `-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage` flags.

I am loading, and testing the shared library in Python via the ctypes python routines.

Gcda files do not get generated from python as my python binary was not linked with the `-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage` flags.

If I run python from `lldb/gdb` then gcda files are generated as `lldb/gdb` were compiled with the appropriate coverage flags.

Is it possible to call the appropriate coverage functions to initialize profile-arcs, and test-coverage prior to calling functions in my shared library, and then call the appropriate coverage closing routines?

I did a nm on my library and noticed the following routines, but am not sure how to call them.

```
___llvm_gcov_init
___llvm_gcov_flush
___llvm_writeout_files
```

It seems like llvm_gcov_init takes parameters so I cant call it directly from python.

I would like to initialize code coverage directly, and not need to recompile python with coverage on multiple machines.

Comment: Hi I ran into a similar issue, Did you know how to figure it out ?

Comment: nope did you figure it out?